# Generate random XML document

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, random

i try to create an app with some questions. I want button to generate random questions but I couldn't find anything so far (some shorter solution if possible). Thank you :)

something.java file code:

```
public class something extends Activity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.somethingXML);

}
public void generate (View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ???? .class);
    startActivity(intent);
}}
```

somethingXML.xml layout file code:

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30pt"
        android:text="@string/buttonM"
        android:id="@+id/buttonM"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:onClick="generate"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Simply if I use button with id "generate", I want to generate it random xml page, but Intent(this, ???? .class) has only one option [example: Intent(this, question1.class)], but I do not want user to solve question1 page always he turns this app on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 10 questions then write following code to generate `random numbers from 1 to 10, and then call your`intent`in`switch case`

```
Random r = new Random();
int randNum = r.nextInt(10 - 1) + 1;
Intent intent = null;

switch(randNum) {
    case 1  :intent = new Intent(this, question1.class); break;
    case 2  :intent = new Intent(this, question2.class); break;
    case 3  :intent = new Intent(this, question3.class); break;
    .
    .
    .
    case 10 :intent = new Intent(this, question9.class); break;
    default :intent = new Intent(this, question1.class); break;
}
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: sadly, I expect approximately 100 questions... but I will use this if nothing else will help. Thank you!

Comment: @Jiří You can use this for 100 questions too. But this is not a good idea to do the task. You can generate the questions on single activity, no need to create 100 activities.

Comment: Anyway, this solution above has some issues with frames anytime It generates new link (in API):    09-27 18:48:02.938 2502-2646/com.example.ji.myapplication I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
09-27 18:48:03.738 2502-2502/com.example.ji.myapplication I/Choreographer: Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-27 18:49:51.788 2502-2646/com.example.ji.myapplication E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xae4312a0
09-27 18:49:53.461 2502-2646/com.example.ji.myapplication (and so on)

Comment: Well, if I use this method above it somehow works, but if it has issues with 10 questions, wanna see how it will work with another 90... so probably would be better something else...

Comment: @Jiří I tried to answer your question. And the error you are getting has nothing to do with my answer

Comment: Yeah I thank you for Your advice, I just wrote if anybody has another idea. I am BIG beginner, I started week ago with android to write just one app and done :) I didn't want to learn how to program android but i need just one app. This is only one problem I could not solve...

Comment: @Jiří thats ok. Happy coding :)